# how to increase the number of xticks displayed in datetick?

Tags: matlab, figure

In the following code, I want to increase the number of ticks in the x-axis in each subplot from 2 to 4 (or in general to any number that I want). Currently, it shows only 12 am-12 am. Any help will be appreciated.

```
x=rand(96,1);
y=rand(96,1);
z=rand(96,1);

Ts=900;


t = 0:Ts:24*3600-Ts; %time in second
time = datestr(t/86400+datenum(2014,1,1)); %time starting at 2014/01/01

subplot(1,3,1)
ts_x = timeseries(x, time);
plot(ts_x)
datetick('x','HHPM')
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;
set(gca,'fontsize',16)


subplot(1,3,2)
ts_y = timeseries(y, time);
plot(ts_y)
datetick('x','HHPM')
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;
set(gca,'fontsize',16)


subplot(1,3,3)
ts_z = timeseries(y, time);
plot(ts_z)
datetick('x','HHPM')
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;
set(gca,'fontsize',16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a way to do it, say by having 5 ticks:

```
 xt=ax.XTick;
 ax.XTick=linspace(xt(1),xt(end),5);
 ax.XTickLabels=datestr(ax.XTick,'HHPM');
```

just place this after you've defined `ax` in your code.

Comment: Or instead of your 3rd line: `datetick('x','HHPM','keepticks')`

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much.